# How to dynamically compose an OR query filter in Django?

Tags: python, django

From an example you can see a multiple OR query filter:

> > > Article.objects.filter(Q(pk=1) | Q(pk=2) | Q(pk=3))

For example, this results in:

```
[<Article: Hello>, <Article: Goodbye>, <Article: Hello and goodbye>]
```

However, I want to create this query filter from a list. How to do that?

e.g. [1, 2, 3] -> Article.objects.filter(Q(pk=1) | Q(pk=2) | Q(pk=3))