# How to dynamically compose an OR query filter in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-q

From an example you can see a multiple OR query filter:

```
Article.objects.filter(Q(pk=1) | Q(pk=2) | Q(pk=3))
```

For example, this results in:

```
[<Article: Hello>, <Article: Goodbye>, <Article: Hello and goodbye>]
```

However, I want to create this query filter from a list. How to do that?

e.g. `[1, 2, 3] -> Article.objects.filter(Q(pk=1) | Q(pk=2) | Q(pk=3))`

Comment: You appear to have asked this twice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/852404/

Comment: For this specific use case you'd probably use `Article.objects.filter(pk__in=[1, 2, 3])` in modern django, but the question is still relevant if you want to do something a bit more advanced by OR'ing Q objects together.

Answer (score 200, accepted):

You could chain your queries as follows:

```
values = [1,2,3]

# Turn list of values into list of Q objects
queries = [Q(pk=value) for value in values]

# Take one Q object from the list
query = queries.pop()

# Or the Q object with the ones remaining in the list
for item in queries:
    query |= item

# Query the model
Article.objects.filter(query)
```

Comment: Thanks! This was what I was looking for :) Didn't know you could do |=

Comment: You could also initialize the query using: query = Q()

Comment: you can make dynamic fields by using \*\*{'fieldname': value}:
**queries = [Q(\*\*{'fieldname': value}) for value in values]**

Comment: How can you compose raw queries with Django if you want to add optional conditions like above?

Comment: That didn't work for me, I don't know why. queries return zero results for me

Answer (score 95):

To build more complex queries there is also the option to use built in Q() object's constants Q.OR and Q.AND together with the add() method like so:

```
list = [1, 2, 3]
# it gets a bit more complicated if we want to dynamically build
# OR queries with dynamic/unknown db field keys, let's say with a list
# of db fields that can change like the following
# list_with_strings = ['dbfield1', 'dbfield2', 'dbfield3']

# init our q objects variable to use .add() on it
q_objects = Q(id__in=[])

# loop trough the list and create an OR condition for each item
for item in list:
    q_objects.add(Q(pk=item), Q.OR)
    # for our list_with_strings we can do the following
    # q_objects.add(Q(**{item: 1}), Q.OR)

queryset = Article.objects.filter(q_objects)

# sometimes the following is helpful for debugging (returns the SQL statement)
# print queryset.query
```

Comment: For newcomers to this thread, like myself, I think this answer should be regarded as the top answer. It is more Djangoesque than the accepted answer. Thank you!

Comment: I would debate that it is more pythonic to use the builtin OR and AND operators (| and &).  `q_objects |= Q(pk=item)`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: Worth noting that if `list` happens to be empty you'll return the equivalent of `Article.objects.all()`. Easy to mitigate by returning `Article.objects.none()` for that test though.

Comment: After much googling and tearing my hair out, I found this simple, clean solution. Thank you

Comment: @Wil you can also initialize `q_objects` with `Q(id__in=[])`. It will always fail unless ORed with something and the query optimizer will handle it nicely.

Answer (score 48):

A shorter way of writing Dave Webb's answer using [python's reduce function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reduce):

```
# For Python 3 only
from functools import reduce

values = [1,2,3]

# Turn list of values into one big Q objects  
query = reduce(lambda q,value: q|Q(pk=value), values, Q())  

# Query the model  
Article.objects.filter(query)
```

Comment: Looks like the "builtin" reduce was removed and replaced with `functools.reduce`.  [source](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins)

Comment: Thanks @lsowen , fixed.

Comment: And it's possible to use `operator.or_` instead of the lambda.

Answer (score 45):

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import or_
from django.db.models import Q

values = [1, 2, 3]
query = reduce(or_, (Q(pk=x) for x in values))
```

Comment: Ok, but where does the `operator` came from?

Comment: @mpiskore: Same place as every other Python module: you import it.

Comment: funny. that was really my question: in which module/library can I find it? google didn't help much.

Comment: oh, I thought it was some sort of Django ORM operator. How silly of me, thanks!

Answer (score 25):

Maybe it's better to use sql IN statement.

```
Article.objects.filter(id__in=[1, 2, 3])
```

See [queryset api reference](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/ref/models/querysets/#in).

If you really need to make queries with dynamic logic, you can do something like this (ugly + not tested):

```
query = Q(field=1)
for cond in (2, 3):
    query = query | Q(field=cond)
Article.objects.filter(query)
```

Comment: You could also use `query |= Q(field=cond)`

Answer (score 10):

See the [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in-bulk-id-list):

```
>>> Blog.objects.in_bulk([1])
{1: <Blog: Beatles Blog>}
>>> Blog.objects.in_bulk([1, 2])
{1: <Blog: Beatles Blog>, 2: <Blog: Cheddar Talk>}
>>> Blog.objects.in_bulk([])
{}
```

Note that this method only works for primary key lookups, but that seems to be what you're trying to do.

So what you want is:

```
Article.objects.in_bulk([1, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 10):

Solution which use `reduce` and `or_` operators to filter by multiply fields.

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import or_
from django.db.models import Q

filters = {'field1': [1, 2], 'field2': ['value', 'other_value']}

qs = Article.objects.filter(
   reduce(or_, (Q(**{f'{k}__in': v}) for k, v in filters.items()))
)
```

p.s. `f` is a new format strings literal. It was introduced in python 3.6

Answer (score 7):

In case we want to programmatically set what db field we want to query:

```
import operator
questions = [('question__contains', 'test'), ('question__gt', 23 )]
q_list = [Q(x) for x in questions]
Poll.objects.filter(reduce(operator.or_, q_list))
```

Answer (score 6):

## For loop

```
values = [1, 2, 3]
q = Q(pk__in=[]) # generic "always false" value
for val in values:
    q |= Q(pk=val)
Article.objects.filter(q)
```

## Reduce

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import or_

values = [1, 2, 3]
q_objects = [Q(pk=val) for val in values]
q = reduce(or_, q_objects, Q(pk__in=[]))
Article.objects.filter(q)
```

Both of these are equivalent to `Article.objects.filter(pk__in=values)`

## Why `Q()` is dangerous

It's important to consider what you want when `values` is empty. Many answers with `Q()` as a starting value will return *everything*. `Q(pk__in=[])` is a better starting value. It's an always-failing Q object that's handled nicely by the optimizer (even for complex equations).

```
Article.objects.filter(Q(pk__in=[]))  # doesn't hit DB
Article.objects.filter(Q(pk=None))    # hits DB and returns nothing
Article.objects.none()                # doesn't hit DB
Article.objects.filter(Q())           # returns everything
```

If you *want* to return everything when `values` is empty, you should AND with `~Q(pk__in=[])` to ensure that behaviour:

```
values = []
q = Q()
for val in values:
    q |= Q(pk=val)
Article.objects.filter(q)                     # everything
Article.objects.filter(q | author="Tolkien")  # only Tolkien

q &= ~Q(pk__in=[])
Article.objects.filter(q)                     # everything
Article.objects.filter(q | author="Tolkien")  # everything
```

`Q()` is *nothing*, not an always-succeeding Q object. Any operation involving it will just drop it completely.

Comment: That was great explaination covering diff scenarios. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use the |= operator to programmatically update a query using Q objects.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere? I have been searching for the last 15 minutes, and this is the only thing I can find.

Comment: Like so much in our industry, it is documented on StackOverflow!

Answer (score 2):

This one is for dynamic pk list:

```
pk_list = qs.values_list('pk', flat=True)  # i.e [] or [1, 2, 3]

if len(pk_list) == 0:
    Article.objects.none()

else:
    q = None
    for pk in pk_list:
        if q is None:
            q = Q(pk=pk)
        else:
            q = q | Q(pk=pk)

    Article.objects.filter(q)
```

Comment: You could use `q = Q()` instead of `q = None`, then remove the `if q is None` clause - slightly less efficient but can remove three lines of code. (The empty Q is subsequently merged away when the query is run.)

Answer (score 1):

Another option I wasn't aware of until recently - `QuerySet` also overrides the `&`, `|`, `~`, etc, operators. The other answers that OR Q objects are a better solution to this question, but for the sake of interest/argument, you can do:

```
id_list = [1, 2, 3]
q = Article.objects.filter(pk=id_list[0])
for i in id_list[1:]:
    q |= Article.objects.filter(pk=i)
```

`str(q.query)` will return one query with all the filters in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Found **solution for dynamical field names**:

```
def search_by_fields(value, queryset, search_in_fields):
    if value:
        value = value.strip()

    if value:
        query = Q()
        for one_field in search_in_fields:
            query |= Q(("{}__icontains".format(one_field), value))

        queryset = queryset.filter(query)

    return queryset
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

easy..
    from django.db.models import Q
    import you model
    args = (Q(visibility=1)|(Q(visibility=0)&Q(user=self.user)))  #Tuple
    parameters={}  #dic 
    order = 'create_at' 
    limit = 10

```
Models.objects.filter(*args,**parameters).order_by(order)[:limit]
```