# how to do this search logic in django

Tags: python, django

I am writing a small search engine for my page in django.

my query code:

```
sterm = request.GET.get('searchterm')
books = Book.objects.filter(title__iregex=r"\y{0}\y".format(sterm))
```

One issue with this code is, if I search for `"python test"`, it is giving me only books which have `"python test"` in their title. But I also need books which have only `"python"` or `"test"` in their title. I know, I can use `Q`. But i am in need for some efficient lookup, i am thinking about this logic:

```
sterms = sterm.split()
if len(sterms) == 1:
   books = Book.objects.filter(title__iregex=r"\y{0}\y".format(sterm))
else: 
   for each in sterms:
      ## how can I gather here all Q's?
   #then this?
   books = Book.objects.filter("gathered Q's with |")
```

how can I gather `Q` filters and then pass it to query? am I ok with this logic or is there more efficient and cooler way of doing this?

Comment: You should take a gander at the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Comment: I missed pasting another link :P https://bradmontgomery.net/blog/adding-q-objects-in-django/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see how to make a dynamic OR'd together query at [How to dynamically compose an OR query filter in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852414/how-to-dynamically-compose-an-or-query-filter-in-django).

Do you need to do it this way, though? Case-insensitive regex queries are quite slow.

Are you using PostgreSQL for your data store? If so, you could investigate the full-text indexing capabilities. That would give you a much faster way to perform these kinds of searchers.

Comment: yeah i am using postgresql. thanks for guidance, i think i will take this full text indexing thanks