# How to query django m2m for a single instance that satisfies multiple requirements?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

For the sake of example, I have the following Django models:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
```

(because books regularly have multiple authors, and authors regularly write multiple books)

Now say I have a list of authors' names as tuples:

```
author_list = [('clarke', 'arthur'), ('herbert', 'frank'), ('asimov', 'isaac')]
```

Is there a way to query for all Books whose `authors` m2m field has at least one `Author` instance that satisfies

```
author.last_name = pair[0]
author.first_name = pair[1]
```

for some pair in author_list?  I.e. to get all books contributed to by at least one of a given list of authors?

The query I *want* to write looks like this:

```
Book.objects.filter(
    authors__first_name__in=[pair[1] for pair in author_list],
    authors__last_name__in=[pair[0] for pair in author_list]
)
```

but that doesn't work, because then all permutations (Arthur Herbert, Frank Asimov, Isaac Clarke, etc...) are allowed.  But I'm not sure how to say, essentially:

'Select all books who have *an* author that satisfies these two things at once.'

or really:

'Select all books who have *an* author whose pair of (last_name, first_name) is in this list of tuples.'

Is there a clean way to do that search in django?

Comment: Try using ``Q`` object. You may concatenate 2 Q objects with ``|`` or ``&``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [build a query using Q objects.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

Based on your answer, but without using `reduce` and `operator`:

```
query = Q()
for last_name, first_name in author_list:
    Q |= Q(authors__last_name=last_name, authors__first_name=first_name)
Book.objects.filter(query)
```

Comment: oo that's awesome I didn't know `|=` is a thing!

Answer (score 1):

I think you could build a query using q objects

`Q(last_name=pair[0], first_name=pair[1]) | Q(last_name=pair2[0], first_name=pair2[1])`

The above query should generate get books with last name clark AND first name arthur OR last_name herbert and first_name frank.

There are quite a few answers on how to do this dynamically:

[How to dynamically compose an OR query filter in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852414/how-to-dynamically-compose-an-or-query-filter-in-django)

You will probably have to twiddle with the query and inspect the query django generates to verify that it is what you intend

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think this works:

```
query = []
for last_name, first_name in author_list:
    query.append(Q(authors__last_name=last_name, authors__first_name=first_name))
query = reduce(operator.or_, query)
Book.objects.filter(query)
```

but please still answer if you see something better!