# Django filter iexact on a list

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a user model set up like this.

```
class ExternalUserModel(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    # other fields

class MyUserModel(models.Model):
    external_user = models.ForeignKey(ExternalUserModel)
    # other fields
```

And I am trying to get a list of MyUserModel from a list of emails.

This is the query I'm tying to perform:

```
MyUserModel.objects.filter(external_user__email__iexact__in=user_emails)
```

But I'm getting this error:
`Unsupported lookup 'iexact' for EmailField or join on the field not permitted.`

I need iexact since the list of emails are based on user input and may not match the casing stored in the data base.

How should I go about making this query?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Django ORM doesn't directly support that. I don't think the database back ends do either. You can get the results you're looking for by combining multiple `__iexact` filters as shown in the various answers here: [How to dynamically compose an OR query filter in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852414/how-to-dynamically-compose-an-or-query-filter-in-django)

Of the options shown there, I prefer the `reduce(operator.or_, ...)` syntax over for loops, but that's personal preference.

Comment: Thanks!
`query = reduce(operator.or_, (Q(external_user__email__iexact=x) for x in user_emails))`
`MyUserModel.objects.filter(query)`
did the trick!

Answer (score -2):

An email must be complete, so, it should be exact, you don't need to use the `__iexact` lookup. You just need:

```
MyUserModel.objects.filter(external_user__email__in=user_emails)
```

Comment: This takes case into account, ie `email@example.com` is different from `Email@example.com`