# Optimizing Django get queries

Tags: django, django-models, query-optimization

I have Django code similar to this:

```
for obj in some_list:
    m1obj = Model1.objects.get(a=obj.a, b=obj.b, c=obj.c)
    Model2(m1=m1obj, d=obj.d, e='foo').save()
```

I did optimize the insert into `Model2` using `bulk_create`, however, this is still painfully slow because of the `get` from `Model1` (**~45sec** for 3k inserts).

I also tried adding:

```
class Meta:
    index_together = [
        ('a', 'b', 'c'),
    ]
    unique_together = [
        ('a', 'b', 'c'),
    ]
```

The `unique_together` helps a little, `index_together` didn't seem to have much effect.

I have a cumbersome workaround for this doing:

1. Filter `Model1` getting all the objects I will need ordered by by one or more keys, e.g. `order_by('a', 'b')`, and make sure Django caches the result, e.g. `len()`
2. Use binary search (`from bisect import bisect_left`) to locate the first `a` then `b` ... etc (although there are much fewer `b`s and `c`s so just iterating is the same.

This reduces the insert time to jus over **3 seconds**!

There must be a better, cleaner and maintainable way to do this. Any suggestions?
Is there a way to filter/get (smartly) within Django's cache query results?

**EDIT**: Changed `d='foo'` to `d=obj.d` - any bulk get needs to be mappable to the tuple it belongs to otherwise I cannot the create Model2 entry.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a single query (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852414/how-to-dynamically-compose-an-or-query-filter-in-django)) that will fetch only the results that you need so no need to sort and binary search later.

I have not tested it so I don't know whether it will be faster than what you are already doing or not. Also as the SQL query will be large (according to number of records in `some_list`) so this query might raise error if it exceeds size defined in MySQL settings by parameter `max_allowed_packet` (By default 16MB as mentioned [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/packet-too-large.html)).

```
import operator
from django.db.models import Q
query = reduce(operator.or_, (Q(a=obj.a, b=obj.b, c=obj.c) for x in values))
model1_objs = Model1.objects.filter(query)
```

Then you can do `bulk_create` with `Model2`.

```
Model2.objects.bulk_create([
    Model2(m1=m1, d='foo', e='bar')
    for m1 in model1_objs
])
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your suggestion is much slower than doing the `get()` sequentially. I stopped it after 3+ minutes. Also, as I mentioned in my edit, this could (should?) have worked if parameters 'd' and 'e' were constant. Since they are not, I have no way to map `model1_objs` to the correct `obj.d` as DB queries do not guarantee an order.

Answer (score 0):

How many rows does Model1 has? if it is relatively small (less than 50k) you can fetch all using filter then compare the tuple in python.

How about "some_list" is small list (less than 100), if it is you can the Q keyword to filter everything at once.

```
first = some_list.pop()
conditions = Q(a=first.a, b=first.b, c=first.c)
for obj in some_list:
    conditions |= Q(a=obj.a, b=obj.b, c=obj.c)

Model1.objects.filter(conditions)   # this will get your all the Model1 from ur list
```

Q object Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#q-objects

Comment: This solution is the same as what @muhammad-tahir suggested. For the 3K rows I killed the query after a few minutes. For smaller groups it isn't much faster (it at all) than separate queries. I did improve the workaround to create a tuple to table row map, which is both fast and readable, but if rows would be 100K and not 3K I might run into memory problems...