# When using Q objects in django queryset for OR condition error occured

Tags: python, django

I want to use filter with OR condition in django.
For this i want to use Q objects.
My code is this

```
def product(request):
    try:

        proTitle = request.GET.get('title')
        ProDescription = request.GET.get('description')


    except:
        pass


    list0 = []
    result = Product.objects.filter(Q(title__contains=proTitle ) | Q(description__contains=ProDescription ) )

    for res in result:

        list0.append(res.project_id)
    data ={'title result':list0}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data))



return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
```

When pass all value that is `proTitle,ProDescription
it working fine.
If any value is going to none it encounter a error`Cannot use None as a query value`
Why this error occured when i am using OR operator into my queryset

I am also try this

`result = Project.objects.filter(title__contains=proTitle) | Project.objects.filter(description__contains=ProDescription )`

but same error occured
I am unable to understand actually what is the problem

Comment: please help me in this why q object is not working for me

Answer (score 2):

You may set the defaults of the `get` method to something other than `None`, say empty string:

```
proTitle = request.GET.get('title', '')
ProDescription = request.GET.get('description', '')
funAria = request.GET.get('funAria', '')
femaleReq = request.GET.get('femaleReq', '')
```

This is however likely to return all results in the DB when using `__contains`.

Otherwise you may build the Q functions discarding all `None` values.

Use this as a guideline: [How to dynamically compose an OR query filter in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852414/how-to-dynamically-compose-an-or-query-filter-in-django)

Comment: It returns me all objects

Comment: @vikrant He notes that in his answer. You will have to follow a dynamic pattern like in the link or my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can build the `Q` object in a loop, discarding all values that are none. Note that after consideration, it appears that your `except` will never be reached because `get` will simply return `None` if the Get parameter is not present. You can thus replace the `try` with an `if`.

The following code assumes that you simply want the unset values to be ignored in the filter.

(This is untested--let me know if you have any issues.)

```
attributes = (('title', 'title__contains'),
              ('description', 'description__contains'),
              ('funAria', 'functional_area__contains'),
              ('femaleReq', 'female_candidate'))

query_filter = Q() # initialize

for get_param, kw_arg in attributes:
    get_value = request.GET.get(get_param)
    if get_value:
        query_filter |= Q(**{ kw_arg: get_value })

result = Product.objects.filter(query_filter)
```

Comment: Is there any problem inmy models.py

Comment: @vikrant I just edited--I mistakenly thought that `get` threw an error instead of just returning `None`. Did you try the updated code?

Comment: Same error occured.I updated my code with your code.Please have a look on it.

Comment: @vikrant Are you sure it's the *same* error message: `Cannot use None as a query value` ? I noticed that you misspelled `Productt`...

Answer (score 0):

Your error seems to mean that one of your values is `None`:

```
def product(request):
    try:

        proTitle = request.GET.get('title')
        ProDescription = request.GET.get('description')
        funAria = request.GET.get('funAria')
        femaleReq = request.GET.get('femaleReq')
        someIntValue = request.GET.get('someIntValue')

    except:
        pass

    allQs = Q()
    if proTitle is not None: 
        allQs |= Q(title__contains=proTitle )
    if ProDescription is not None:
        allQs |= Q(description__contains=ProDescription )         
    if funAria is not None:
        allQs |= Q(functional_area__contains=funAria )
    if someIntValue is not None:
        allQs |= Q(some_int_value__gte=someIntValue) # no need to convert someIntValue to an int here as long as you are guaranteed it is unique.
    allQs |= Q(female_candidate=femaleReq )
    list0 = []
    result = Product.objects.filter(allQs)
    for res in result:

        list0.append(res.project_id)
    data ={'title result':list0}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: i want to add two more field  cost_gte = int(request.GET.get('cost_gte'))
     cost_lte = int(request.GET.get('cost_lte'))

Comment: how can i add.when i am adding this and send no value it gives me error.refrence before assignment