# How to search for multiple keywords over multiple columns in Django

Tags: django, search, django-models, django-queryset

I want to be able to input a list of strings like so:

`["searchterm1", "searchterm2", "searchtermN"]`

And **output all rows** from the database where `"searchterm1"` matches one of the columns **OR** `"searchterm2"` matches one of the columns and so on.

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: you can use django [Q](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) for or query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import Q

def search(request):

    list_ = ["searchterm1", "searchterm2", "searchtermN"]

    q_object = Q(title__icontains=list[0]) | Q(description__icontains=list[0])

    for item in list_[1:]:
        q_object.add((Q(title__icontains=item) | Q(description__icontains=item)), q_object.connector)

    queryset = Product.objects.filter(q_object)
```

[reference1](https://bradmontgomery.net/blog/adding-q-objects-in-django/)
[reference2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852414/how-to-dynamically-compose-an-or-query-filter-in-django)