# django query set error (istartswith)

Tags: sql, django

I tried :

```
objects_list = Feed.objects.filter(
            job__istartswith__in=['AW', "cons", "S1"])
```

it shows me following error:

```
FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'istartwith' for CharField or join on the field not permitted.
```

if i tried like below, its working:

```
 objects_list = Feed.objects.filter(
                job__istartswith='AW')
```

what should I do for searching words startswith for the list of words in query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django ORM does not support `istartswith__in`, I guess this is because database systems don't support that operation explicitly either.

You should use OR over several clauses in order to achieve this:

```
from django.db.models import Q
objects_list = Feed.objects.filter(
    Q(job__istartswith='AW') | 
    Q(job__istartswith='cons') |
    Q(job__istartswith='S1'))
```

Comment: that list contains many objects not only 3 values, it may be 20 also

Comment: You can build the query dynamically too. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852414/how-to-dynamically-compose-an-or-query-filter-in-django .