# Django filter objects based on list values

Tags: python, django, django-models, filter, orm

I have a listTextField in my modal called `technology`. I want to filter objects based on an array, if every array value is present in the `technology` field.

```
tech = ['a','b',....] #dynamic list
mentors_list = Mentor.objects.filter(
            **{"technology__contains" : value for value in tech}) #this doesn't work
```

Mentor class has (among other fields) :

```
class Mentor(Meta):
    technology = ListTextField(
        base_field=models.CharField(max_length=20),
        size=10, max_length=(10 * 11))
```

Basically i want all objects in `mentor_list` whose `technology` field must contain all the values from `tech` array ( but may contain some extra values ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [`documentation`](http://django-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_fields/list_fields.html#contains) You can chain `Q` object with `&` to check multiple entries contains in the `ListTextField`.

```
from functools import reduce 

technologies = ['a','b'] # your dynamic list

queries = [Q(technology__contains=technology) for technology in technologies]

query = reduce(lambda x, y: x & y, queries)

mentors_list = Mentor.objects.filter(query)
```

Ref: [How to dynamically compose an OR query filter in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852414/how-to-dynamically-compose-an-or-query-filter-in-django)

Comment: Glad to help you. :)