# passing multiple values to a single column name when filtering records in django

Tags: django, django-filter, django-filters

I'm trying to filter records in `django`. The issue is that I want to pass multiple values in the filter method.

Example : `brand = laptops.object.filter(brand__icontains="apple")`
In this example, as far as I know, I can pass one value to the `brand__icontains`.

I want to filter the records with more than one value. Like filtering laptops based on brand like apple, dell, hp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to dynamically compose an OR query filter in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852414/how-to-dynamically-compose-an-or-query-filter-in-django)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the '__in' parameter and pass the array of values like this:

```
brand = Laptops.objects.filter(brand__contains=['dell', 'apple']
```

__in QuerySet [Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#in)