# Django-filters how to use BooleanFilter to range or else

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-filter

Good day, a question about "django-filters", "rest framework"

How to make a filter to
-1 option took up to 50% (in the decimal model), 
-2 option after 50%, 
-3 option  equal 50

I did it with Boolean Filter and an additional "method" function - two fields, if true, then output the corresponding queryset. However, they are tied through one field and, accordingly, use one queryset, which makes them mutually exclusive when called at the same time, and not complementary as I need.
I'm still looking at "ChoiceField", but I don't know if it's possible.

p.s. I tried to unite use union method in functions but get error
"ORDER BY not allowed in subqueries of compound statements."

MY code from filter class:

```
class ProductsFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    type_one = filters.BooleanFilter(field_name='percentage_field', method='filter_one')
    type_two = filters.BooleanFilter(field_name='percentage_field',  method='filter_two')
    type_half = filters.BooleanFilter(field_name='percentage_field', method='filter_half')

    def filter_one(self, queryset, name, value):
        if value is True:
            return queryset.filter(percentage_field__range=(50.1, 100))
        else:
            return queryset

    def filter_two(self, queryset, name, value):
        if value is True:
            return queryset.filter(percentage_field__range=(0, 49.9))
        else:
            return queryset
    def filter_half(self, queryset, name, value):
        if value is True:
            asd = queryset
            return Product.objects.filter(percentage_field=50)
        else:
            return queryset

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['name','price']
```

Filtering by one and by several at once filters, combining queryset and not exclude each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following answers

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77374474/21259369 and
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/852481/21259369

I used Multiple Choice Filter and query union Q() with a trick here  "queries_set |= query"  and i got multiple combined and single selection.

```
from django.db.models import Q

from django_filters import rest_framework as filters

from apps.products.models import Product


class ProductsFilter(filters.FilterSet):

    percentage_field = filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(
        choices=[
            ("bef50", "<50"),
            ("eq50", "50"),
            ("aft50", ">50"),
        ],
        method="filter_percentage_field",
        label="Choose percentage"
    )

    def filter_percentage_field(self, queryset, name, values):
        request = []
        for value in values:
            if value == "bef50":
                request.append(Q(percentage_field__gt=50))
            elif value == "eq50":
                request.append(Q(percentage_field=50))
            elif value == "aft50":
                request.append(Q(percentage_field__lt=50))

        queries_set = request.pop()
        for query in request:
            queries_set |= query

        return queryset.filter(queries_set)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['percentage_field']
```

Answer (score 1):

AS you mentioned, you can use the **`ChoiceFilter(...)`** filter as follows

```py
class ProductFilter(FilterSet):
    percentage_field = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(
        choices=[
            ("type_one", "Type One"),
            ("type_two", "Type Two"),
            ("type_half", "Type Half"),
        ],
        method="filter_percentage_field",
    )

    def filter_percentage_field(self, queryset, name, value):
        if value == "type_one":
            return queryset.filter(percentage_field__gt=50)
        elif value == "type_two":
            return queryset.filter(percentage_field__lt=50)
        elif value == "type_half":
            return queryset.filter(percentage_field=50)
        return queryset

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ["percentage_field"]
```

I've updated the filtering logic using `lt` & `gt` lookup expressions since that makes more sense. Feel free to update the logic in your code as per your business logic.

Comment: Thank you, Sir, you pointed me in the right direction.